# SQL Server total Duration of value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a table containing the following (example below):

```
Device varchar(90)  Value varchar(1000)  Date_time datetime2(7)
---------------------------------------------------------------
device1                  10              2017-30-11 13:55
device1                  50              2017-30-11 14:00
device1                 100              2017-30-11 14:45
device1                  50              2017-30-11 14:55
```

Currently the date_time column is updated everytime the value column is updated.

The above is just  an example - this table is much larger.

What I am trying to achieve is to return a table for the last 7 days showing the total duration that device1 had a value of 10, a value of 50 and so on -
I'm not sure if this is possible with the data I have.

Edited: what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
Device           Value         Last_seven_days
--------------------------------------------------
device1            10          5 hours
device1            50          5 hours 10 minutes
device1           100          3 hours 5 minutes
```

How the time is displayed isn't that important - as long as it includes hours & minutes

Comment: What do you mean with total duration? difference between data_time?

Comment: the sum of the duration of each value - ie. for how many hours and minutes this week was the devices value = 50, or, for how many hours and minutes this week was the device value = 10

Comment: in your sample data device1 had the value 10 for 5 minutes, yet in your desired output you wrote 5 hours. So what is the correct formula ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion- the first table is just a "snapshot" of the entire table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take into account periods prior to the starting time. I've provided a test table to help verify times.

```
DECLARE @testtable TABLE (Device varchar(90), [Value] varchar(1000), Date_time datetime2(7))
INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES
 ('device1', '10', '2017-11-29 13:55:00')
,('device1', '50', '2017-11-29 14:00:00')
,('device1', '100', '2017-11-29 14:45:00')
,('device1', '50', '2017-11-29 14:55:00')
,('device2', '20', '2017-11-20 02:45:00')
,('device2', '23', '2017-11-23 00:00:02')
,('device3', '03', '2016-01-01 00:00:00')
,('device3', '04', '2016-10-03 03:59:00')

DECLARE @startdate datetime = '2017-11-23 00:00:00'
       ,@enddate   datetime = '2017-11-30 00:00:00'

SELECT dT.Device
      ,dT.Value
      ,RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, CASE WHEN @startdate > dT.Date_time
                                               THEN @startdate
                                               ELSE dT.Date_time
                                         END, dT.endtime) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),3) + ':' + 
       RIGHT('0' + CAST((DATEDIFF(second, CASE WHEN @startdate > dT.Date_time
                                                THEN @startdate
                                                ELSE dT.Date_time
                                          END, dT.endtime) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, CASE WHEN @startdate > dT.Date_time
                                               THEN @startdate
                                               ELSE dT.Date_time
                                         END, dT.endtime) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) AS [Time Passed]
  FROM (
        SELECT *
               --is null when the last status has been reached for a device
              ,COALESCE((SELECT MIN(Date_time) 
                           FROM @testtable T2 
                          WHERE T2.Device = T1.Device AND T2.Value <> T1.Value
                                AND T2.Date_time > T1.Date_time     
                        ), @enddate ) AS endtime
          FROM @testtable T1
       ) AS dT
WHERE dT.EndTime > @startdate
```

Produces:

```
Device   Value  Time Passed
device1  10     00:05:00
device1  50     00:45:00
device1  100    00:10:00
device1  50     09:05:00
device2  20     00:00:02
device2  23     167:59:58
device3  04     168:00:00
```

Comment: Just looking back over this again - is it possible to get the total of all the time passed where the machine and value are the same - ie device 1     50       (sum of all time passed where devvice is 1 and values i 50) etc

Comment: @EdwardDoyle The seconds need to be aggregated using SUM, grouped by the Device and Value.  Please see the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77957/1

Comment: cheers for your help - I've update the table - would really appreciate if you could take a look - I've added a start and finish time columns - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe112/1/0

Comment: @EdwardDoyle It's a little easier with start and endtime, but the idea is the same.  We still take the SUM of seconds grouped by Device and Value: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe112/7

Comment: cheers for the update - I think my biggest issue is trying to figure out at what points to run sub queries, cast, convert etc! - I have one further curve ball if you wouldn't mind taking a look - I am trying to add another column (sum of total time for each device) then the percentage of this that the device was in each value - also if end_time is null or empty then use the current time (-the device may still be in that value) - cheers!  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe112/17/0

Comment: For Nulls, you can use COALESCE in the DateDiff function.  For the percentage it is tricky because two different levels of granularity are used for the SUM: one grouped at Device and Value; the other grouped at just Device.  You can Inner Join the aggregates at the Device level (see link), and this should work as expected since both levels of granularity have device.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe112/21

Comment: Cheers - just twiddling the query a bit - I'll post my results in the next day or so - sound for your help @zorkolot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` to get the next date/time:

```
select t.*,
       lead(date_time, 1, getdate()) over (partition by device order by date_time) as next_date_time
from t;
```

Then, you assuming that "7 days" is based on the `date_time`, you can do some filtering and aggregation:

```
select device1, value,
       sum(datediff(second, date_time, next_date_time)) as duration_in_seconds
from (select t.*,
             lead(date_time, 1, getdate()) over (partition by device order by date_time) as next_date_time
      from t
     ) t
where date_time >= dateadd(day, -7, cast(getdate() as date))
group by device1, value;
```

Comment: I'll attempt this when I am in front of my work machine thanks - also, can this be executed as one query or does this have to be executed one after the other as above -  also does t.* here just represent select * from table

Comment: @EdwardDoyle  .  . . `t` represents the alias for your table.